# jQuery Block UI: node is undefined

Tags: jquery

I'm close to finishing an app that uses quite a bit of JS. Recently Firebug started throwing an error that says "node is undefined", referring to  data.parent = node.parentNode; on line 209 of jQuery blockUI plugin Version 2.31 (06-JAN-2010) @requires jQuery v1.2.3 or later. I'm using jQuery 1.4.2

When I remove the code from my page that triggers the Block UI action, the error is still there. So it does not seem to be an issue in my code but an "error" in the file itself, or perhaps some kind of conflict with another file?

For info my code is below. My IDE is highlighting some syntax errors in here but it does that even when there are none. Perhaps I'm missing it?

```
 $.blockUI({ css: { 
                border: 'none', 
                padding: '25px', 
                backgroundColor: '#fff', 
                '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                opacity: 1, 
                color: '#000' ,
                cursor: 'auto'
            },
                message: $('#block_ui_msg'),
             });
```

EDIT: I just replaced the block UI file with the latest version 2.33 (29-MAR-2010), error still occurs but this time on line 210.

Comment: did you find a solution to this issue? I'm going through the same thing...

Answer (score 8):

`block_ui_msg` is not defined in your page.

Comment: Mine was defined, but I had to call the html `$('#block_ui_msg').html()` to make it work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would think the additional `,` after the `message:` would give a syntax error. Not sure about the blockUI plugin, however.

Answer (score 0):

Hi the answer is actually quite simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#demo1').click(function() { 
    $.blockUI({ message: $('#loginForm') }); 

    setTimeout($.unblockUI, 2000); 
});
```

});

I had the same problem but sorted it out.
If you read carefully that working example you will see the 2 elements here with the IDs demo1 and loginForm. The script is searching these nodes and will throw an error if not found. So double check how are your nodes block_ui_msg if it is in the source.